# Syntax error when using array in bash script with husky

Tags: bash, husky

In my pre-commit husky hook I'm display a select option to select the semantic version("Patch" "Minor" "Major"). When initialize the array I get this error `.husky/post-commit: 20: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. This line is the initilization of the options array.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/config.cfg"

scriptsDir=$(echo "$(pwd)/scripts");
. "$scriptsDir/select.sh"

echo "\nSemantic version: ${darkGray}(use arrow keys)${noColor}"
echo

selectOptions=("Patch" "Minor" "Major")

select_option "${selectOptions[@]}"
choice=$?

echo "Choosen index = $choice"
echo "        value = ${selectOptions[$choice]}"
```

The `select_option` renders a text based list of options that can be selected by the
user using up, down and enter keys and returns the chosen option. I don't think the issue is there as I tested it in test.sh script and it worked just fine.

Error:

```
.husky/pre-commit: 20: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 2 (error)
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: The error indicates that `sh` is some shell other than `bash` (likely `ash` or `dash`).

Comment: You need to run the script with bash, not just sh, to get array support. See ["Difference between sh and Bash"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash).

Comment: Why are you using the "bash" tag for a script that's running with `#!/usr/bin/env sh`? (Even when `sh` is a symlink to bash, it runs in compatibility mode that turns off many bash-only features when started under the sh name).

Comment: BTW, `$(pwd)` is more efficiently replaced with `$PWD`, and if you _do_ switch to bash from sh, using `$0` to find the location of that script is more reliably replaced with `$BASH_SOURCE`. ([`$0` is unreliable](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) even when using sh; but if you don't switch to bash, there's no more-reliable alternative available).

Comment: Thank you all. Since this question is duplicated, I'll delete it in a bit.